# How to redefine mouse click onto Firefox' address bar to work as Ctrl+L

Tags: firefox, mouse, address-bar, focus

I want to increase my personal privacy, and I mean it from the ground.

I deleted Windows and have Linux only.

I bought a VPN with cryptocurrency, decided to move away from Chrome and Google as a whole.

As a result I need a high quality browser now, I've picked Firefox.

I am in a process of adjusting it to my needs...

I know there is a keyboard shortcut doing exactly what want Firefox to do when I left click on address bar.. i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

But I am unable to redifine it, does anyone know a solution already maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enter the Firefox internal configuration:

   ```
   about:config
   ```
2. Find the following setting:

   ```
   browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll
   ```
3. Enable it, i.e. set it to:

   ```
   true
   ```

That's it, your single-click now behaves like you are used to from Google Chrome.